# How to suppress "Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in"

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using some plugins in APEX5.0 and need to know how can we suppress the plugin errors which are raised by default when a wrong input in entered.
I have date picker items on my apex page, when entering the date e.g. when a wrong date format is entered then an exception "Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in" pops up. Even when I use my own "user defined" validation code to validate date , when enter the wrong date format , the error "Error in PLSQL code raised during plug-in" appears always and I need to press Ok for more than 10 times to clear this error from the page.
Could you please suggest the way to suppress this error?

Comment: is it a choice for you if you're going to handle that validation on the "change" event of that item?

Comment: The right way to handle this is to find out what the errors are, how they occur, and how to deal with them. Not suppress them and find out later on how nasty it is to have suppressed them. Without seeing code it's impossible for anyone to tell what is going wrong.